# Group queryset by field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am working with [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I have a model called `Selection` that contains field called `category`, when i query the model to send the result to the frontend i get it with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "SHOES",
    "products": 122,
    "created_at": "2021-09-11",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category": "SHOES",
    "products": 4,
    "created_at": "2021-10-07",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "category": "CLOTHES",
    "products": 0,
    "created_at": "2021-10-08",
  },
]
```

I need to put the selections of the same category in an array and remove the grouped-by category, like this:

```
{
   "SHOES": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "products": 122,
       "created_at": "2021-09-11",
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "products": 4,
       "created_at": "2021-10-07",
     }
   ],
   "CLOTHES": [
     {
       "id": 3,
       "category": "CLOTHES",
       "products": 0,
       "created_at": "2021-10-08",
     }
   ]
}
```

I considered to making it with `Javascript` in the frontend, but before i wanted to know if there's a way to do this from Django.

Comment: Share `Selection` model and serializer. I'm pretty sure it can be done with `many=True` flag

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do some customisation in your code.

1. Get all categories by using values_list('category', flat=True) with your queryset
2. Iterate through them filtering category one by one

```py
    response_list = []
    categories = Selection.objects.values_list('category', flat=True)
    for category in categories:
        data = Selection.objects.filter(category=category)
        data = {
            category: SelectionSerializer(data, many=True).data,
        }
        response_list.append(data)
```